# Controlling TCP connection at packet level

Tags: http, tcp

I'm having an issue with some embedded mobile devices that have a buggy TCP stack. We're trying to update these devices but the firmware download fails, unless the mobile connection is very very good. Since it's an EDGE connection, it's usually bad.

Part of the problem is that the devices need quite a bit of time to write the data to storage. This is probably what leads to packet loss, but the connection never recovers.

I'm thinking that if I could control the connection at TCP level, I might be able to get around this problem. We tried changing the congestion control and it doesn't help, but we're still looking into that.

In the meantime I'd like to look into this option. Is there any way to do it, without writing my own TCP stack / kernel module?

Comment: Packet loss is benign in TCP until the retry timers expire. Further information required,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any way to do this so in the end I set up a new server and recompiled the linux kernel with a modified TCP_RTO_MAX value (5s instead of 120s). This seems to have solved my problem. My guess is that the network was not the actual issue but rather devices taking too long to store the data. This is a very specific case and this solution wouldn't help in any situation where the network connection is actually slow.